# How do I return the results from a query in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to return the results from a query.  I have read 100 questions, but they all just show me how to log the results.  My query appears to be successful, but my client does not receive the response.

```
export const myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>
{
    const collection = getMyCollection();
    let query = collection.orderBy('time', 'desc');
    return query.get().then((snapshot) =>
    {
        return snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
        {
            console.log("This prints");
            return doc.data();
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Note:  Before marking this as a duplicate, please notice that none of the similar questions talk about returning the results.

Comment: "My query appears to be successful, but my client does not receive the response."  How do you send the data to the client?

Comment: You add the `google-cloud-functions` tag in your question. In what kind of Cloud Function your code is used? Can you share the full code of this function?

Comment: what kind of your function? `onCall` or `onRequest`?

Comment: I thought Google Cloud Functions/Firestore was same thing as Firebase Functions/Firestore.  I guess they are not.  I updated the code, but cannot create new firebase tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const myFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) =>
{
    const collection = getMyCollection();
    let query = collection.orderBy('time', 'desc');
    return query.get().then((snapshot) =>
    {
        return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    }
}
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/75s7p2/get_all_documents_to_get_array_of_usable_data/do8x99f?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Answer (score -1):

A `querySnaphot` is returned. [The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query) shows:

```
var museums = db.collectionGroup('landmarks').where('type', '==', 'museum');
museums.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
    });
});test.firestore.js
```

Comment: This is interesting, I wasn't aware there is `collectionGroup()` 

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I was asking about returning the data, not logging it.

Comment: so, add a `return` the `.get` (`return museums.get()...`. In any case, [`querySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) is accessed as an array.